# How to delete tabPages?

Tags: c#, .net

I have TabControl that contain n tabPages(WinForm poject).

At some point I want to delete tabPages with specific name.

How do I implement it with optimal running time complexity?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `System.Linq` to find the tabPage with the desired name. If it exists you can remove it.

```
var tabPage = tabControl1.TabPages.OfType<TabPage>()
    .FirstOrDefault(o => o.Name == "SpecificName");

if (tabPage != null)
{
    tabControl1.TabPages.Remove(tabPage);
}
```

You can create an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx) to make it simpler

```
public static class TabControlExtender
{
    public static void Remove(this TabControl t, string name)
    {
        var tabPage = t.TabPages.OfType<TabPage>()
            .FirstOrDefault(o => o.Name == name);

        if (tabPage != null)
        {
            t.TabPages.Remove(tabPage);
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
tabControl1.Remove("SpecificName");
```